# $E \subset [0,2\pi]$ has positive measure, for any sequence $t_n$ of real numbers, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E \cos(n x + t_n)\,dx = 0?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Assume that $E \subset [0, 2\pi]$ has positive measure. For any sequence $t_n$ of real numbers, do we have$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_E \cos(n x + t_n)\,dx = 0?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\cos(nx+ t_n) = \cos (nx) \cos t_n -\sin(nx)\sin t_n,$$
so

$$\int_E \cos(nx+t_n)dx = \cos t_n \int_ E \cos(nx) dx -\sin t_n \int_E \sin (nx) dx.$$

As

$$\int_E \cos(nx) dx , \int_E \sin(nx) dx \to 0$$
and $\cos t_n, \sin t_n$ are bounded, we also have

$$\int_E \cos(nx+t_n) dx \to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

We are looking at the real parts of

$$\tag 1\int_E e^{i(nx+t_n)}\,dx = e^{it_n}\int_E e^{inx}\,dx.$$

By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, the integrals on the right $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Since $|e^{it_n}| = 1$ for all  $n,$ $(1)\to 0,$ hence so do its real parts.